# Need help in htaccess redirect in a php project

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com to http://www.mydomain.com/index

I am using that code in htaccess file but not working

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/index [r=301,L]
```

I have also try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/index [r=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/index [r=301,L]
```

But not working so Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing 2 things.

1. You can use the `[OR]` flag in your conditions, or simply combine the regex
2. You are causing a redirect loop so you need to *not* redirect `/index`

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/index [r=301,L]

Or if you only want to redirect requests for the **root**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mydomain.com/index [r=301,L]
```

Comment: Ya you are right. i was using a loop of redirect. You have given right answer. I like it. Thank you very much.